# Description under text

Tags: beamer

**Update** I did it this way:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{\textbf{Lorem ipsum example}}
    \vspace{1mm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mycircle/.style = {circle, draw = black, minimum width =2.8cm},               
myrect/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, minimum width = 2 cm, minimum height = 2 cm}, mybig/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, minimum width = 7.4cm, minimum height = 2.4 cm}, auto, node distance = 2cm]


\node[inner sep=0pt] (lorem) at (0, 0) {\large Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit};

\node[below of = lorem, xshift = -4.5cm, yshift = 0cm] (foo) {\textbf{foo}};

\node[below of = lorem, xshift = -1.6cm, yshift = -0.5cm] (bar) {\textbf{\emph{bar}}};

\node[below of = lorem, xshift = 1.2cm, yshift = -0.55cm] (this) {\textbf{\emph{this}}};

\node[below of = lorem, xshift = 4.5cm, yshift = 0cm] (ok) {\textbf{is ok}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (refFoo) at (-3.8, -0.3) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (refBar) at (-0.9, -0.3) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (refThis) at (0.8, -0.3) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (refOk) at (3.8, -0.3) {};

% ---------------
\path[-latex, thick] (refFoo) edge [] node {} (foo);
\path[-latex, thick] (refBar) edge [] node {} (bar);
\path[-latex, thick] (refThis) edge [] node {} (this);
\path[-latex, thick] (refOk) edge [] node {} (ok);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{block} 
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

I want to insert a text and a description with arrows, as in figure

Comment: Some examples connecting text and figures with beamer: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/, http://texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

Comment: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/ I tried this, but i wasn't able to use it without equation environment

Now I'm trying with this http://texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something to start:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\huge](A) {This is a simple text};
\draw[->] ([xshift=5mm]A.south west)--++(250:1cm) node[below]{Something};
\draw[->] ([xshift=-10mm]A.south)--++(260:2cm) node[below]{Something else};
\draw[->] ([xshift=5mm]A.south)--++(280:1.5cm) node[below]{More things};
\draw[->] ([xshift=-5mm]A.south east)--++(300:2cm) node[below]{something};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already did this way, I'm wondering if this could be done without tikz picture

Comment: @clfmaris What exactly do you want to do without tikz picture? You can always draw it with any other tool and import as pdf, jpg, ... with `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: I did the way you suggested and also in other manner, I edited the question with my solution even if it is longer